# How to compute similarity between two license.txt files?

Tags: file, text, information-retrieval, similarity

I would like to compute similarity between licenses' txt files so I could then based on the license.txt identify to which license it corresponds. What kind of information retrieval technique should I use? Once I programmed tf-idf but I am not sure whether this is applicable here. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been working on this issue for 3+ years, let me tell you it's far from trivial, and you are not going to solve it with a single algorithm, let alone tf-idf and cosine similarity.

There are a number of challenges, I write some of them:

1. similar license texts (agpl/gpl/lgpl, bsd/apache1.1/openssl, mit/isc/curl) are extremely difficult to disambiguate, and would have an extremely high cosine similarity (unless you are very smart about feature selection, maybe...)
2. same applies to different versions of the same license (lgpl 2.0/2.1)
3. LICENSE.TXT files often contain multiple licenses
4. bsd notices are very hard to catch, ie. you have the same text, except for the rights holder

You will end up using a combination of approaches, there's no silver bullet unfortunately.

Comment: bad news :S i guess i'll have to do some part with the exact string matching and the rest i'll inspect manually... e.g. if license text contains this url http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt it means for sure that it is Apache Version 2.0.

Comment: Checkout the Fossology project. This is an attempt to created automated scanning of source for licenses and other kinds of IP identification. Savino is absolutely correct there is no silver bullet. The Linux foudation's SPDX project is at least finally standardising on a common set of identifiers for known open source licenses. If developers start using them in the source code headers it would make parsing the source much much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) to index all Licenses as documents (each Lucene document is a License). When you have a new license.txt you want to check which licene it corresponds to, you can just query lucene using the whole license.txt as a query.

That would be using TF-IDF and all the IR stuff. But you could also use something more specific to the problem, like checking specific keywords.